# I am getting this error "ld: framework not found Flutter" after upgrade xcode latest Version 13.4.1 (13F100). tried all solution but not succeed

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

[This is the screenshot of error after running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0F4u.png)

Here is
flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.0.2 at /Users/magespider/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cd41fdd495 (9 days ago), 2022-06-08 09:52:13 -0700
    • Engine revision f15f824b57
    • Dart version 2.17.3
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/magespider/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macOS  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.115
    ! Error: Bhavin’s iPod is not connected. Xcode will continue when Bhavin’s iPod is connected. (code -13)
    ! Error: iPhone is busy: Waiting to connect and unlock the device. Xcode will continue when iPhone is finished. (code -10)
    ! Error: iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when iPhone is connected. (code -13)
    ! Error: Bhavin’s iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when Bhavin’s iPhone is connected. (code -13)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Please help to resolve this issue, Thanks in advance

I tried the following solution

1. Deleted ios folder and then recreated
2. pod deintegrate, install
3. delete podfile, podfile.lock the Pods folder, and install the pod again.
4. tried to change the Other Linker Flag in Runner -> Build settings,
5. Added arm64 in Excluded Architecture.

Comment: Please try "flutter pub cache repair" and try to run again.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh for your solution,  I tried this also, But not working

Comment: I Fixed this issue by downgrading the Flutter SDK.